# Using Python Web GET data

Tags: python, form-data

I'm trying to pass information to a python page via the url. I have the following link text:

```
"<a href='complete?id=%s'>" % (str(r[0]))
```

on the complete page, I have this:

```
import cgi
def complete():
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    db = MySQLdb.connect(user="", passwd="", db="todo")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute("delete from tasks where id =" + str(form["id"]))
    return "<html><center>Task completed! Click <a href='/chris'>here</a> to go back!</center></html>"
```

The problem is that when i go to the complete page, i get a key error on "id". Does anyone know how to fix this?

*EDIT*
when i run `cgi.test()` it gives me nothing

I think something is wrong with the way i'm using the url because its not getting passed through.

its basically *localhost/chris/complete?id=1*

*/chris/* is a folder and complete is a function within *index.py*

Am i formatting the url the wrong way?

Comment: If the error occurs when some form sends data to the Complete page, then you need to include the form in your question.  It doesn't appear to have a field named id.

Comment: BTW, when changing server state (a SQL DELETE) it is considered best practice to use a POST (then a redirect), not a GET.

Comment: more info: http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=RedirectAfterPost

Answer (score 1):

The error means that `form["id"]` failed to find the key `"id"` in `cgi.FieldStorage()`.

To test what keys are in the called URL, use [cgi.test()](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.test):

> cgi.test()
>
> Robust test CGI script, usable as main program. Writes minimal HTTP headers and formats all information provided to the script in HTML form.

EDIT: a basic test script (using the python cgi module with Linux path) is only 3 lines. Make sure you know how to run it on your system, then call it from a browser to check arguments are seen on the CGI side. You may also want to add [traceback formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html#module-cgitb) with  `import cgitb; cgitb.enable()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
cgi.test()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing out the value of form to make sure you're getting what you think you're getting? You do have a little problem with your code though... you should be doing form["id"].value to get the value of the item from FieldStorage. Another alternative is to just do it yourself, like so:

```
import os
import cgi

query_string = os.environ.get("QUERY_STRING", "")
form = cgi.parse_qs(query_string)
```

This should result in something like this:

```
{'id': ['123']}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should make dictionary lookups via

```
possibly_none = my_dict.get( "key_name" )
```

Because this assigns None to the variable, if the key is not in the dict. You can then use the

```
if key is not None:
    do_stuff
```

idiom (yes, I'm a fan of null checks and defensive programming in general...). The python documentation suggests something along these lines as well.

Without digging into the code too much, I think you should reference

```
form.get( 'id' ).value
```

in order to extract the data you seem to be asking for.

Comment: The doc shows a cgi.FieldStorage() example:

  if not (form.has_key("name") and form.has_key("addr")):
    ...

Comment: form.get( 'id' ).value doesn't work either. I get an attribute error. I think something is wrong with the way i'm using the url because its not getting passed through

Comment: to see what is being passed, use cgi.test()